# Is there a way to preview how pages will break in Markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I am writing documentation in Markdown which I will need to convert into a PDF. However, when converting to a PDF using [this Visual Studio Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf) it adds pages and occasionally the pages will break at awkward moments.

Is there a way to view how these pages will break before converting to a PDF?

Comment: How are you converting to PDF? In any case, Markdown itself has no idea about this. It's a text format, and the most common target format is HTML which doesn't have page breaks.

Comment: I am using a Visual Studio code extention called "Markdown PDF" by yzane. I need to submit documentation for my school work which is why I thought a PDF would make the most sense. I am open to other alternatives as well if PDF is not the best file type to convert to.

Comment: Are you printing this or only on-screen?  HTML doesn't have page breaks but css does.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an alternative. You can use this css style directly as well:

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;" />
```

What can be useful, to fit more stuff in one page, is to change the font and figure scale by changing the [scale in settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf#markdown-pdfscale):

```
"markdown-pdf.scale": 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything about previewing breaks in the docs, but you can [manually insert page breaks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf#page-break):

> Please use the following to insert a page break.
>
> ```
> <div class="page"/>
> ```

Breaking before headings, for example, might be a good way to partly mitigate this issue.